# Jumphost VM not able to communicate with LAN

Tags: networking, virtualization, ip, virtual-machines, local-area-network

I have setup a jumphost VM on WinXP. It has 2 NICs.

NIC1, which is the LAN, has the following IP settings:

IP: 10.0.0.1 /24
(No default/ DNS configured)

NIC2, which has external connections, has the following settings:

IP: 10.105.218.121 /24
Default GW: 10.105.218.1
DNS: (A Functioning DNS is configured)

I can connect to the internet as it is taking the NIC2 default GW. But, it is not able to communicate with entities over HTTP, that are within the LAN. Pings to this entity are successful.

The browser on my jumphost VM can't connect to this.

**But, another VM which has only 1 NIC for the LAN, can easily connect to the aforementioned entity's web portal.**

Therefore, I believe the problem lies with the jumphost VM not selecting the NIC properly.

**Is there any way to restrict LAN traffic to only NIC1 so the connection is successful?**

**Pictures**

*Jumphost VM*

[image: Jumphost VM]

*Another VM*

[image]

**EDIT**

I forgot to add that I've tried setting a proxy and trying too. Sorry about that. Here's what happens when the proxy is

**ENABLED:** *Internet works, LAN doesn't*

[image]

**DISABLED:** *Internet does not work, LAN DOES*

[image]

***** Bypass option isn't helping *****

Comment: Paron me for stating what appears to be obvious: The Jumphost VM browser is configured to use a proxy server, which is refusing the connection. I would look in that direction. If you're not using a proxy server then Firefox is misconfigured.

Comment: ^ I'm sorry for missing that aspect. I've edited the question accordingly. Sorry.